# How to get the spectrum of an element of $\mathbb{C}^{2}$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

I know the definition of the spectrum, which is not invertible in an algebra $\mathbf{A}$.

For a complex vector space $\mathbf{A}=\mathbb{C}^2$, define the norm:
$$\| (a_1,a_2)\| = \max\{|a_{1}|,\, |a_{2}|\}.  $$

$\mathbf{A}$ is a Banach space, and define the product law and involution:
$$ab=\langle a_{1}b_{1},a_{2}b_{2}\rangle , \ \ \ a^{*}=\langle \bar{a_{1}}, \bar{a_{2}}\rangle.$$

Now, $\mathbf{A}$ is a $C^{*}$ algebra. Problem about the maximal ideals I have asked here: [The Gelfand transform of a example: a complex vector space $\mathbf{A}=\mathbb{C}^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2727827/the-gelfand-transform-of-a-example-a-complex-vector-space-mathbfa-mathbbc)

But about the spectrum of an element $\lambda \in \sigma(a)$ means that $\lambda e-a=\langle \lambda-a_{1}, \lambda-a_{2}\rangle $ is not invertible. $\textbf{How to write more specifically about the $\sigma(a)$?}$

Comment: You don't offer a "representation" of the spectrum of $A$, so how can one possibly help you "represent it more accurately"?

Comment: It is not clear if you are asking about the spectrum of an element or the spectrum of the algebra (two fairly different things).

Comment: @Aweygan sorry...I mean how to get the $\sigma(a)$?

Comment: @MartinArgerami Sorry, I want to ask the spectrum of an element.

Comment: What does it mean for an element $(a_1,a_2)$ of this space to be invertible? It means that $a_1\neq0$ and $a_2\neq0$.  Given that, when is $(\lambda-a_1,\lambda-a_2)$ invertible?  When is it not invertible?

Comment: @Aweygan Do you mean the $\sigma(a)$ is just the $<a_{1},a_{2}>$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A useful point of view is to note that $\mathbb C^2=C(\{1,2\})$, the algebra of continuous functions on the discrete set with two points.

So we might as well find the spectrum of $f\in C(X)$, where $X$ is any Hausdorff compact space. A function will be invertible in $C(X)$ when $1/f$  makes sense: so we need $f\ne0$, or $|f|>0$. Because of continuity and compactness, this condition is also sufficient:

> $f\in C(X)$ is invertible if and only if $f(x)\ne0$ for all $x$.

Now, $\lambda\not\in\sigma(f)$ precisely when $f-\lambda$  is invertible. By the above, when $f(x)-\lambda\ne0$ for all $x$. That is to say, when $\lambda$ is not in the image of $f$. It follows that  $\lambda\in \sigma(f)$ if and only if $\lambda$ is in the image of $f$. In other words, 
$$
\sigma(f)=\{f(x):\ x\in X\}.
$$

Comment: +1 Thanks a lot!!!